# extraer elementos de un arrgelo

Tags: c++

**mi problema es el siguiente crear un codigo que reciba (pida por teclado) una cadena de texto de una ecuación de segundo orden y que halle las raíces usando la fórmula general.
Por ejemplo: “x^2+8x+15=0” o
“8x+15+x^2=0” voy a obtener x1 = -3 y x2 = -5.
mi pregunta es cómo puedo extraer sus coeficientes y símbolos de tal forma que pueda convertirlos a números y operarlos en la formula cuadrática tomando en cuenta que la ecuación puede estar escrita en desorden

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
string texto;
cout << "Ingresa una cadena de texto: ";
cin >> texto;
vector<char> caracteres; // Vector para almacenar cada letra
for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) { //La función length() en C++ se utiliza para 
obtener la longitud de una cadena de texto
    caracteres.push_back(texto[i]); // Agregar cada letra al vector
}
// Imprimir las letras almacenadas
cout << "Las letras almacenadas son: ";
for (int i = 0; i < caracteres.size(); i++) {
    cout << caracteres[i] << " ";
}
return 0;
}
```

e probado este código para almacenar la cadena de texto en un vector con la idea de poder dividirlo y tomar los valores de entre sus posiciones, pero no se me ocurre como tomar valores dentro de el con la precisión necesaria para reorganizarlo en la estructura de una cuadrática**

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste o investigaste? Tal vez sea útil usar regex. También encontré una respuesta que te podría ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/1806116/13419694

Answer (score 1):

Bueno realize este pequeño programa para que lo analizes como un paso incial y te sirva de ejemplo para resolver tu ejercicio. La resolucion de ecuaciones es de izquierda a derecha asi que debes operar los datos que vayan ingresando y separarlos en listas.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<char> operands;
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int num = atoi(argv[i]);
        
        // Revisa si atoi() funciono correctamente
        if (num != 0 || (num == 0 && argv[i][0] == '0')) {
            // Entonces lo agrego a mi lista de numeros
            numbers.push_back(num);
        } else {
            // Sino lo pongo en mi lista de operadores
            operands.push_back(argv[i][0]);
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "Numeros ingresados:\n";
    for (auto i : numbers)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    
    std::cout << "\nOperadores ingresados:\n";
    for (auto i : operands)
        std::cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Input

```bash
./main.exe 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 - 2
```

Output

```bash
Numeros ingresados:
1 2 3 4 5 2
Operadores ingresados:
+ + + -
```

Pues nada a partir de aqui tienes que hacer las validaciones para prevenir que escriban cualquier cosa, como separar los coeficientes de las variables y respetar los parentesis. Pero primero tu programa debe soportar suma y multiplicacion. Hay bastante que escribir pero saldra eventualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Esta funcion te ayudara a lo que necesitas:

```
    
// Función para obtener los coeficientes de la ecuación cuadrática
tuple<int, int, int> obtener_coeficientes(string ecuacion) {
    // Eliminar espacios en blanco y convertir la ecuación a minúsculas para simplificar el análisis
    for (char &c : ecuacion) {
        c = tolower(c);
    }
    ecuacion.erase(remove_if(ecuacion.begin(), ecuacion.end(), ::isspace), ecuacion.end());
    
    // Utilizar expresiones regulares para encontrar los coeficientes
    // Los patrones buscan números con o sin signo seguidos de 'x^2', 'x' o sin 'x'
    regex patron("([-+]?\\d*)[x^]*2*([-+]?\\d*)[x^]*([-+]?\\d*)");
    smatch coincidencias;
    regex_search(ecuacion, coincidencias, patron);

    // Convertir los coeficientes encontrados a enteros
    int a = stoi(coincidencias[1].str());
    int b = stoi(coincidencias[2].str());
    int c = stoi(coincidencias[3].str());

    return make_tuple(a, b, c);
}
```